# including correct version of header file in eclipse CDT

Tags: eclipse-cdt

Hi I am working in a C based project. Here I need to include sched.h in my project. But the problem is inside linux there is multiple sched.h in multiple directory (after installing the linux headers).

Now my question is how to select the proper version of header file which I want to include in my project?

Answer (score 0):

Just `#include <sched.h>` in your program. It is a standard posix header and
the compiler will find the right one in its default include directories
without any help.